# Duplicate components with state values [Updated code for problem]

Tags: reactjs

I have a view that has multiple cards with values inside each one.

I can duplicate a card. However, this doesn't preserve the values in the duplicated card.

If Card A has values inside of its state, how can I tell Parent View to create a Card B with Card A values?

Here is my view. I'm rendering multiple cards

```
 {items.map((item, i) => (
            {
                'VideoCard': <div><Droppable onChange={droppableResponse} /><CreateVideoCard onChange={cardActionResponse} i={i} /></div>,
                'AudioCard': <div><Droppable onChange={droppableResponse} /><CreateAudioCard onChange={cardActionResponse} i={i}></CreateAudioCard></div>,
                'DescriptionCard': <div><Droppable onChange={droppableResponse} /><CreateDescriptionCard onChange={cardActionResponse} i={i}></CreateDescriptionCard></div>,
                'BreakdownCard': <div><Droppable onChange={droppableResponse} /><CreateDescriptionCard onChange={cardActionResponse} i={i}></CreateDescriptionCard></div>,
                'Terms': <div><Droppable onChange={droppableResponse} /><CreateTermsCard onChange={cardActionResponse} i={i}></CreateTermsCard></div>
            }[item]
        ))}
```

When a card sends a response such as delete or duplicate, I go into my cardActionResponse function. Here is the duplicate part:

```
  if (event[0] == 'duplicate') {
            //Retrieve item from items array at location event[1] 
            console.log(items[event[1]])
            var data = JSON.stringify(event[2])
            console.log(data)
            //Retrieve information about which card was duplicated. Not just AudioCard but AudioCard w/ info
            items.splice(event[1], 0, items[event[1]])
            forceUpdate()
        }
```

Var data returns the duplicated data that I need to insert into my new duplicated card. However this will require me to change up my current structure of my cardList

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([
    'VideoCard',
    'AudioCard' ,
    'DescriptionCard',
    'BreakdownCard',
    'Terms',
]);
```

In addition, I need the ability to send to each card what location it is (i) and I was able to do that with the items.map function.

I'm thinking about creating something like

```
<CreateVideoCard onChange={cardActionResponse} i={I} data={data} />
```

Then in my createvideocard component, I'll check if the data is empty, if not I'll swap the states.

Is there an easier way I can duplicate components with state inside? This seems a little extra?

Comment: Hi.   There are lots of ways to tackle that.  What have you tried?  Share some code so folks can provide you with some advice that fits your situation.

Answer (score 0):

if you post some code it will be helpful to answer.

Anyway, as you have not done that, here is a proposed soln.

pass a callback function say onDuplicate() from parent to cardList--> card. card component should call that function onClick of duplicate.

this onDuplicate function will update the parent state.. here is a sample example

```
const data = [{
      id: 1111,
      name:"some name",
    //THERE ARE OTHER FIELDS I HAVE NOT ADDED
    }]

    const CardList = (props) => (
      <div>
        {props.profiles.map(profile => <Card key={profile.id}  onDuplicate={props.onDuplicate}  profile={...profile}/>)}
      </div>
    );

    class Card extends React.Component {

      duplicate = ()=>{
        console.log(this.props)
        this.props.onDuplicate({...this.props.profile,id: 222})
      }
      render() {
        const profile = this.props.profile;
        return (
          <div className="github-profile">
            <img src={profile.avatar_url} />
            <div className="info">
              <div className="name">{profile.name}</div>
              <div className="company">{profile.company}
              </div>
              <div><button onClick={this.duplicate}>duplicate</button></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }



    class App extends React.Component {
      state = {
        profiles: data,
      };

      onDuplicate = (profileData)=>{
        console.log("+++++++"+profileData.name+""+profileData.company)
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          profiles: [...prevState.profiles, profileData],
        }));
      }
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <CardList profiles={this.state.profiles} onDuplicate={this.onDuplicate}/>
          </div>
        );
      } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `duplicate` function should be inside the card and then call a function in the parent passing the current state.

```
const Parent = () => {
  const handleDuplicate = (state) => {
    // your logic to create the new card with the initial state
  } 
  <CardA onDuplicate={handleDuplicate}/>
}

const CardA = (props) => {
  const { initialState, onDuplicate } = props;
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);

  const duplicate = () => {
    onDuplicate(state);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The key function I had to use was React.cloneElement

I changed my items array to

```
  const [items, setItems] = useState([
        <CreateVideoCard onChange={cardActionResponse}/>,
        <CreateAudioCard onChange={cardActionResponse}></CreateAudioCard>,
        <CreateDescriptionCard onChange={cardActionResponse}></CreateDescriptionCard>,
        <CreateDescriptionCard onChange={cardActionResponse}></CreateDescriptionCard>,
        <CreateTermsCard onChange={cardActionResponse}></CreateTermsCard>,
    ]);
```

and rendered it with

```
{items.map((item, i) => (
                    React.cloneElement(item, {i: i})
                ))}
```

When I received a request to duplicate I would use cloneElement to add a data prop to my items array:

```
 items.splice(event[1] + 1, 0, React.cloneElement(items[event[1]], { data: data }))
```

Then in my card constructor. I checked if props.data was undefined. If it was, I would swap out the state and if it wasn't, it would create base structure.